# Documents lost contents after updating it

Tags: solr, solr4, solrcloud, sunspot-solr

I posted 3 documents from post.jar and they successfully posted and i also searched any word of those documents so it returns correct document but when i partial update the document means just update one field then then after updating i once again searched for a word but it doesn't reply successfully.means after partial update it lost the contents of the documents. the fields which i updated are defined by me manually means out of those fields which build itself by post.jar.
so what is the solution that after partial update it remains same

Answer (score 2):

Assuming by "partial update" you are talking about the Atomic Update feature, then this will apply:

In order for Atomic Update to *not* lose data, all fields in your schema that are not copyField destinations must have stored="true".  All fields that ARE copyField destinations must have stored="false".

Further details required for proper Atomic Update operation:  The information in copyField destinations must *only* originate from copyField sources.  If some information in copyField destinations originates from the indexing source and some of it comes from copyField, then the information that originated from indexing will be lost when Atomic Update is used.

Also see the "Field Storage" section found on this page from the Solr documentation:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Updating+Parts+of+Documents#UpdatingPartsofDocuments-AtomicUpdates

Comment: also _version_ field ?

Comment: This is the _version_ field definition, along with a comment, from basic_configs in version 6.4.1:

<!-- doc values are enabled by default for primitive types such as long so we don't index the version field  -->
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="false" stored="false"/>

In recent versions, docValues can replace stored, and does so by default.  This particular field is auto-populated by Solr, so I don't think it really matters for Atomic Updates, but for _version_ to function completely correctly for everything else it does, the field must either be stored or have docValues.

Comment: I made all fields stored=true including version field but still it lost the text

Comment: after changing stored=true then i posted files and i can see all texts of the file is stored in _text_ field.

Comment: "id":"E:\\solr-6.4.1\\upload\\arabic.txt",
        "_text_":["E:\\solr-6.4.1\\upload\\arabic.txt",
          "1714",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser",
          "text/plain",
          "UTF-8",
          "E:\\solr-6.4.1\\upload\\arabic.txt",
          "text/plain; charset=UTF-8",
Text of file,
"1562594534266765312"]
but after updating any field the place where text of file was showed now  the updated value of field is showed.

means if i update any field then it replaces the text of file

Comment: the problem is in this field _text_

Comment: These comments do not allow sufficient formatting for a discussion like this.  I am on the #solr IRC channel that lives on the freenode IRC network.  The Solr mailing list is also a good avenue for support.

Info about these resources can be found here:

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/community.html

Comment: if i made another field as copy of this ? what is the way of it

Answer (score 0):

I solved by problem by making stored=false to all dynamic fields and remove copy field of *text*
As all fields are copied in to *text* field so after doing these changes my problem becomes solve.